# Adding a multiple elements from a List to an array

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, list, arraylist

I have a list with multiple variables and would like to add to an array the write to a text file.

```
class DataFields
{
     public string name{get;set;}
     public int id{get;set;}
     public int age{get;set;}
}

List<DataFields> dfList;
```

would look something like

```
Adam 1234 23
Pete 3841 15
Scot 8435 30

DataFields[] result = dfList.ToArray();
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\File\TextFile.txt", result);
```

I would like the result to be displayed in the text file similar to the list above but I am having trouble adding the list to the array then display in that order. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`File.WriteAllLines` wants a collection of strings. You can generate one using LINQ:

```
List<DataFields> dfList = new List<DataFields>();
// populate dfList here

var formattedData = 
     dfList
        .OrderBy(df => df.Name)
        .Select(df => string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", df.Name, df.Id, df.Age));

File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\File\TextFile.txt", formattedData);
```

You should use PascalCase for your property names (Name, Id, Age).

Comment: might need tab/comma separation. Single space delimited could cause difficulty, no?

Comment: Even tab separation could cause difficulty - if something more structured is required then LINQ to XML would be one better choice.

Comment: Not if it's just dumping out to Excel. Then a CSV/Tab separated can natively do that for no additional effort.

Comment: Yes, the OP can change the string formatting if they require a different format. It isn't clear from the description.

Comment: The formatting would be a minute issue. This is perfect for what I am wishing to accomplish. Thank you guys for your input!

Answer (score 3):

```
var result = dfList.Select(df => String.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", df.name, df.id, df.age);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this too..

```
List<DataFields> dfList = new List<DataFields>();
    // populate dfList here
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\File\TextFile.txt");

            foreach (DataFields df in dfList)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(df.id+"\t"+df.name+"\t"+df.age);
            }

            sw.Close();
```

or simply use foreach of List which is more efficient.

```
dfList.ForEach(df=> sw.WriteLine(df.id + "\t" + df.name + "\t" + df.age));
```